# Latex indentation automatically changing for each alternate page

Tags: latex, indentation, page-layout

I am writing my Master thesis document using the cleanthesis package and currently my document looks as below

[image]

The problem with my document is each consecutive page has a different indentation. Seems like all even pages start the content a bit left than all odd pages. I tried to change by so many ways. But every time it is crashing my document compilation. Could you please let me know if there is a quick fix around here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is can be solved by using: `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`

Indentation is used here as when you will print your master thesis, the odd pages are on the right and all even pages are on the left.